# Site harmed by malware -or is it a server problem?

Tags: security, website, malware, block

I have a site which is got harmed by this "spywarepc.info" and showing

> "Your site has been attacked by a
>   Malware"

:( ... don't even know what is this ? so i have opened spywarepc.info in a browser but it's not opening.

My site has been blocked by Google as well? Please help me out from this ... is it malware? How will I recover it?

Please help

Comment: Changes in DNS behaviour (can't read valid anti-malware sites) and crazy warning popups indicate that you have downloaded a trojan. It might not have had time yet to further the infection.

Do this immediately:

Shut the machine down, pull the hard disk, put it in/on a known safe machine as a second drive (a USB<->sata/ide adapter is useful for this), and run a virus/anti-malware scan on it. Do not allow auto-run. Without the malware running, it cannot defend itself from the scan.

Comment: kmarsh: bad advice for a non-technical person :) If you are non-tech, the best thing to do is to go to a store and buy an anti-virus or take your PC to a technician. Generally that's not what people like to hear, but generally works best.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I found the cause to be my FTP Client.

I use FlashFXP. A spyware on my local machine took the site data from my FlashFXP. It then connected to my website and inserted the code in the default page. Next time when site is opened this malicious tihng is downloaded and also google discards this into black-list.

We solved the problem by moving our FTP client to another clean machine and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong forum for it really - but spywarepc.info is a listed malware site itself punting bogus virus checking etc.

You shouldn't use the link to it, and get a proper AV and checked your system.

Answer (score 0):

your bank account has been stolen, please gimme your new credentials

http://mybank.badsite.com/

It's basically the same gig.